# complex CUDA kernel in MATLAB

Tags: cuda

I wrote a CUDA kernel to run via MATLAB,
 with several cuDoubleComplex pointers. I activated the kernel with complex double vectors (defined as gpuArray), and gםt the error message: "unsupported type in argument specification cuDoubleComplex".

how do I set MATLAB to know this type?

Comment: cuDubleComplex? is that a typo?

Comment: cuDubleComplex is a type for complex numbers in c, with 2 double parts. you can use this type with "cuConmplex.h", and manipulate complex numbers on the GPU with a set of functions.

Comment: I understand perfectly well what it is. Look again at what I wrote in my comment and what you wrote in your question. cuDubleComplex and cuDoubleComplex are not the same thing. Which are you using in your code?

Comment: sorry. I ment cuDoubleComplex.

Comment: Right, details matter. Please edit your question to include the *exact* error message produced by the compiler.

Comment: edited. can you help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, you can't.

The list of supported types for kernels is shown [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html), and that is all your kernel code can contain to compile correctly with the GPU computing toolbox. You will need either modify you code to use `double2` in place of `cuDoubleComplex`, or supply Matlab with compiled PTX code and a function declaration which maps `cuDoubleComplex` to `double2`. For example

```
__global__ void mykernel(cuDoubleComplex *a) { .. }
```

would be compiled to PTX using nvcc and then loaded up in Matlab as

```
k = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('mykernel.ptx','double2*');
```

Either method should work.

Comment: It would be good if you could accept this answer. It will take the question off the unanswered question list and make it easier to find by search in the future.